# Why is the timeupdate event called on audio src change HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have an audio file in my markup:

```
<audio class="audio-player">
  <source src="audio/scene_1.wav" type="audio/wav" />
</audio>
```

I am also using JS to create my own audio player with a display of the current time and duration:

```
let audio = $('.audio-player')[0]

audio.ontimeupdate = () => {
  console.log("updated")

  $('.audio-seconds').html(`
    0:0${Math.floor(audio.currentTime)} / 0:${Math.floor(audio.duration)}
  `)
}
```

When the user interacts with certain elements of the page I will update the audio src:

```
$('.audio-player').attr('src', `audio/scene_${g.currentScene.next}.wav`)
```

Interestingly it will go into the [ontimeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event even though the audio was paused before. I'm wondering why this is happening? When I change the `src` of an audio, why is it triggering the `ontimeupdate` event.

I am mixing Vanilla JS and jQuery here but that should not make any difference at all.

Comment: Because the [media element load algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#concept-media-load-algorithm) requires the client to reset the playback position: _"3. Set the current playback position and the official playback position to the earliest possible position"_

Comment: I guess because the time is updated from (something) to zero.  Makes sense.  Maybe check if playback is paused or not in your handler and react accordingly.

Comment: @Andreas thanks, I didn't get the connection how changing the src will affect that event. So it will reset the timer. Maybe you can provide an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that changing the `.src` attribute triggers the [media element load algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#loading-the-media-resource).

Part of this alogrithm (the [resource selection algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#concept-media-load-algorithm)) requires to change the playback position:

> 3. Set the [current playback position](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#current-playback-position) and the [official playback position](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#official-playback-position) to the [earliest possible position](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#earliest-possible-position).

This change will trigger an [timeupdate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-timeupdate) event:

> When the [earliest possible position](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#earliest-possible-position) changes, then: if the [current playback position](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#current-playback-position) is before the [earliest possible position](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#earliest-possible-position), the user agent must [seek](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-seek) to the [earliest possible position](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#earliest-possible-position); otherwise, if the user agent has not fired a [timeupdate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-timeupdate) event at the element in the past 15 to 250ms and is not still running event handlers for such an event, then the user agent must [queue a task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) to [fire an event](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-fire) named [timeupdate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-timeupdate) at the element.